# The Semisimplicial Homology of a Cone

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, simplicial-complex

Given a semi-simplicial set $X_\bullet$ we can define its cone $CX_\bullet$ at each level by $CX_0=X_0\amalg\{*\} $ and $CX_n=X_n\amalg X_{n-1}$. The simplicial operators send a new element of $CX_n$, e.g. $\sigma'\in X_{n-1} $ to the compatible elements in $X_{n-2}$ and to $\sigma$ itself.

I want to show that it is "contractible", that is quasi-isomorphic, to $C\{\emptyset\}$, and the quasi-isomorphism is given by the inclusion $i:C\{\emptyset\}\to CX$.

Some calculations show that the only nonzero epimorphism  $g:CX\to C\{\emptyset\}$ is $g_n=0$ for $n>0$ and $g_0(\sigma)=*$ for every generator $\sigma$.

Of course, $g\circ i=\text{Id}_{C\{\emptyset\}}$. However, I can't show that $i\circ g$ is homotopic (this is a hint in the problem) to the identity on $CX$. Indeed, I need a function $$K:\mathbb{Z}(X_0)\oplus \mathbb{Z}(*)\to \mathbb{Z}(X_1)\oplus \mathbb{Z}(X_0)  $$ satisfying $$ \partial\circ K(a,b)=(0,a+b). $$
Geometrically, I need to find for each vertex in $X$ a combination of edges such that their boundary is $*$. However, the boundary of edges is always "even". So this is where I'm stuck.

Am I doing something wrong? One problem which might be is that I'm trying to find a homotopy for the zero's component. That is $K_0:C_0(CX)\to C_1(CX) $ such that $\partial K_0=f_0\circ g_0$. I mean, perhaps the condition for homotopy is only for higher orders. Unfortulately, no one stressed to us what happens in the zero level at any time in class.

Comment: Your condition is slightly wrong. In degree 0 you need for each vertex $v$ a combination of edges whose boundary is the difference between $v$ and $*$.

Comment: Btw, to sort out the definition of chain homotopy at the edge of the sequence you can define manualy $h_{-1}=0$ and plug into the usual formula. Alternatively, you can imagine your chain complex continuous with zeroes all the way to $-\infty$.

Comment: Which condition is wrong? And in degree 0 of what? Of  g or the homotopy?

Comment: I understand where my confusion was. I was looking for a function $K $ such that $\partial K+K\partial=f\circ g $, while I need it to satisfy $partial K+K\partial=f\circ g -Id $.

Comment: Exactly :) and by "degree zero" I meant the equality that should hold in the abelian group at degree zero of the chain complex.